# Clang не видит заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки c++

Tags: c++, header, sublime-text-3, clang++

Windows 7-32. Установил Sublime text 3, затем пакет EasyClangComplete к нему. Потом скачал сам Clang c официального сайта (пробовал версии 3.7, 5.0, 6.0). Автокомплит кода в саблайме начал работать, но почему-то теперь у меня появились ошибки включения стандартных заголовочных файлов.

[image: ecc error]

В итоге пришел к выводу, что проблема в Clang. Попытался скомпилировать используя clang++ в итоге действительно не находит эти заголовки. Причем виден список папок, в которых происходит поиск, но в которых самих заголовков собственно и нету.

[image: clang error]

Установлен MinGW 6.3.0. И с g++ все компилируется без проблем.
В итоге никак не пойму, как указать Clang'у папки (того же mingw), в которых искать заголовки. Видел похожие темы, вроде бы все попробовал, и все равно не получается. Либо я что-то не так делаю. Не пробовал только [----это----](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525245/getting-clang-to-work-on-windows). Но неужели нету способа проще?

Comment: Попробуйте версию 6.0 с установленной VS2017.